# Using Laravel's Horizon - How to make "monitoring tags" persist

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, horizon

### Problem

I have used the horizon GUI to "monitor tags" and it seems that after a while the tags that I am monitoring disappear and I would need to specify them again. I have kind of a lot of tags I like to monitor (10-20?) so it's annoying to have to keep typing them in when I notice them disappear.

#### Questions:

**How can I make these persist? Why are they getting removed?**

Screenshots are of the GUI showing when I am not monitoring tags and when I am monitoring them.

[image: Screenshot - "You're not monitoring any tags."]

[image: Screenshot - Showing tags being monitored]

#### Additional Info

I am using redis as the cache driver and horizon's connections are set to redis as well. This is true for local and for production. On local it seems when horizon is turned off and then turned back on the tags go away. So I assume these are being stored in cache? I wish there was a way to persist (via config) the tags I want to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable persistence on redis.

https://redis.io/topics/persistence details how to do so.

RDB is good for faster restore and smaller backup sizes but may miss data
AOF can miss less data, but is longer to restore and may be a larger file size (it does periodically compact)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I lose them when I delete the keys:
redis-cli flushall

I restore them with:
redis-cli SADD laravel_horizon:monitoring

Example inside in bash script:
redis-cli SADD laravel_horizon:monitoring email-system email-system-cron salesforce